# Initializing a double array with its size as another variable in c#?

Tags: c#

why is this code invalid

```
int K = 3;
double[,] a = new double[K,K];
```

It exits with the error "*a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field*"

EDIT: I wrote this code inside a class. I am curious what difference it makes if it is inside a class or a method.

Comment: Where did you write this code? In a method or in a class? If you wrote in a class, your `K` is non-static by default and it needs to class reference to get itself like `Class1.K`.

Comment: it works https://dotnetfiddle.net/1APzdi

Comment: If you wrote them in a method, they will be variable.

Comment: I am intimidated by the negative responses I get here for my first question :):).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `a` is a field of an object. Either make `K` static:

```
    static int K = 3;
    double[,] a = new double[K, K];
```

Or initialize `a` in the constructor.

To answer your updated question:

When declared as a field, you can not reference nonstatic members as you can not control the order in which fields are initialized (unless you use the constructor as I suggested). So the compiler cannot say that `K` has been assigned a value before `a` is initialized.

When declared in a method, the `K` has been initialized as it comes first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you expect?

Want to have the array size static, but not having to repeat the dimensions everywhere? Use a constant.

```
const int ArraySize = 3;
double[,] a = new double[ArraySize, ArraySize];
```

Want to have the size depend on a parameter from the outside? Use a parametrized constructor:

```
double[,] a;
public YourClass(int arraySize)
{
  a = new double[arraySize, arraySize];
}
```

Want to have the array and it's size as an actual variable? Don't define it as a field! :)

```
public void YourMethod()
{
  var arraySize = 3;
  var array = new double[arraySize, arraySize];
}
```

Note that in C# (unlike say, Pascal), size of the array is *not* part of the definition. So you don't have to specify it until you actually need to create the array instance, and you can later assign a bigger array to the same reference, for example.

I do not think there is a legitimate reason to have the size be a field, especially if it's not static. Even if static, it reeks of bad design. So think a bit harder about what you're actually trying to do - if it's hard to do in C#, you're probably missing some simple solution to your problem, or you're trying to code a different language in C# :)

The basic reason why you can't write it the way you did as fields of a class, but can use it in a method is simple - methods are an ordered list of instructions to happen. While this is a bit of a simplification, you can think of it as something guaranteed to happen in a particular order. So you first assign `3` to `K`, and then you create a new array using the value of `K`. So far, so good.

On the other hand, fields are *not* guaranteed to be initialized in any given order. It's no longer an ordered list of instructions, the runtime (and compiler) is free to do whatever it thinks is best. By moving the initializations to an explicit constructor, you again impose a fixed order of execution; suddenly, `K = 3` will again always happen before `new double[K, K]`.